# Fetching a newly added record in a database table in django

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a database setup in django(development server) and I have a agent(exe) which is located in remote machine.When I execute the agent the agent will insert the data in servers database(using sql query)
(In agent I have used python MySQLDb to connect & Insert the data in to DB tables.)

At the server end I am waiting in loop to get the record but **I could not find the latest inserted record by using soft_row_obj = EpSoftData.objects.filter(unique_id = un_id)  (Though I could see the entry (manually) in my database)**

my models file :

```
class EpSoftData(models.Model):
    unique_id = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    ip_address = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    soft_data = models.CharField(max_length=15000, blank=True)
    scan_time = models.DateTimeField()
    err_msg = models.CharField(max_length=3000, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'ep_soft_data'
```

Views.py file:

```
def func(un_id):
    while True:
        soft_row_obj = EpSoftData.objects.filter(unique_id = un_id)
        if soft_row_obj :
            return soft_row_obj
            break;
```

agent code:

```
"INSERT INTO ep_soft_data (unique_id, ip_address, soft_data, scan_time, err_msg) VALUES ('%d','%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (self.unique_id, self.ip_address, json.dumps(self.agentDict), self.scanTime, self.err_msg)
```

Django is not loading data in runtime if the record is inserted using a sql Query.
How to get the record??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't think there's enough information here to help.  how are you obtaining un_id that you are passing?  what error do you receive if any?  if no error, what result do you get?

Comment: leave about un_id. If I am trying to get the len of all records available in DB using len(EpSoftData.objects.all()) I am unable to get the newly added record.(I think  model objects unable to load the new records if it is done by using sql query for that perticular session)

Comment: Still missing details.  `len(EpSoftData.objects.all())` returns a number that is less than the number of records in the `EpSoftData` table (determined by inspecting with a "workbench" tool?)

Comment: "I think model objects unable to load the new records if it is done by using sql query for that perticular session"--why do you think that and what evidence do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves my problem, Need to update every time before querying the new value, it's caching.

```
soft_row_obj = EpSoftData.objects.update()
```

Thank you all for your inputs

Answer (score 0):

Views run in transactions by default. Code running inside a transaction doesn't see changes that were done outside the transaction. You should read the [transactions documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/transactions/) to understand how to commit the transaction inside your function, or even disable transaction management altogether.